Echo is appending characters from a previous echo command
I wrote some code, on one line, for a simple count down timer:
#Fixed formatting
i=0;
echo -en "Enter timer length (seconds): "; 
read num; 
echo "Timer starting...now"; 
sleep 1; 
for i in $(seq $num 1); 
  do 
    echo -ne "$i second(s) remaining"\\r; 
    sleep 1; 
  done; 
echo -e "\033[34mTimer Finished\033[0m";

The code works for the most part, but there's something weird happening with the output.
I'm expecting: Timer Finished at the very end of the process, however, I am instead getting: Timer Finishedmaining.
I've tried formatting the strings differently, changing the 'echo' -options, removing terminal escapes... I'm at a loss.

The -n parameter to echo tells it not to emit a newline character at the end of the line. You are seeing the end of the previous message, which is not being cleared by those escape sequences your code is attempting to use.

Also, writing the whole script on one line is not a good idea in general. It's hard to read.

I knew I was overlooking something...simple...
So my code is keeping the previous output, shifting the cursor, then overwriting the output string up to the length of the new output string? (hope this makes sense)

And -e is not recognized by echo on MacOS. edit maybe it is; it doesn't complain but it's not in the man page

Thanks for your answer. Ended up clearing the end of the line for that last output using' \033[0K\r' and I'm getting what I expect!

See the seq section of BadUtils - Greg's Wiki for other ways to improve the code.

@Pointy, what man page are you looking at? echo is a bash builtin, so the echo binary on the file system is not used.

@glennjackman yea that's what I concluded (except it's zsh now and not bash)

That said, echo behavior isn't consistent even if you did know the shell was bash, because it can be configured several different ways -- it'll change depending on whether the xpg_echo flag is set, whether posix is set, &c. It's basically always the wrong tool; people should use printf instead whenever they're doing anything that isn't completely trivial.

If you set the cursor to the beginning of the line after each output of ...seconds remaining and then print a message shorter than that, the remaining text is obviously visible.
But you could delete the text with another ansi escape code <ESC>[K (Clear line from cursor right)
i=0
echo -en "Enter timer length (seconds): "
read num; echo "Timer starting...now"
sleep 1
for i in $(seq $num 1); do 
  echo -ne "$i second(s) remaining\r"
  sleep 1
done
# Print message and "Clear line from cursor right"
echo -e "\033[34mTimer Finished\033[0m\033[K"


This won't work as-intended if xpg_echo and posix flags are set -- better to use printf instead of echo -e (and, for that matter, also instead of echo -n). See Why is printf better than echo? on [unix.se].

(using seq is also a bit unfortunate -- it's neither part of bash nor part of the POSIX standard, so whether it works at all is dependent on OS-specific implementation details; better to use the shell-builtin C-like for loop functionality if you're only targeting bash: for ((i=num; i<=1; i--)); do)

echo only prints what it has been told to print. It does not do anything else, especially it does not clear the rest of the line.
Due to -n and \r at the end of the string, after each string is printed, the cursor goes to the beginning of the (same) line. On the next execution of echo, the provided text (partially) overwrites what has already been printed on that line by the previous invocations of echo.
You can add enough spaces at the end of the last text to make sure that it fully covers the leftovers of the previous executions of echo.
Or you can use an ANSI escape code to clear the rest of the line after printing or the whole line before printing.

echo is not guaranteed to honor -n to mean not to print a newline -- the POSIX spec is such that output is completely undefined when -n is present, so it could print -n on output instead of honoring it, or do literally any other thing. And any shell that interprets -e to mean it should do something other than print -e on output is outright breaking the specification, which is why when bash is configured to be strictly compliant (configuration that can be done either at compile time or at runtime), echo -e behaves in quite unintended ways.

See https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html, particularly including the RATIONALE and APPLICATION USAGE sections.

why after loop finishes the next echo has the text from the previous echo:
because the line is NOT BEING CLEANED which causes after the loop finishes to make the cursor write over the text without cleaning it first
there's 2 solutions:

clean line afterloop:
read -p"Enter timer length (seconds): " num
printf "Timer starting...now\n"
sleep 1
for ((remaining=$num;remaining>=1;remaining--))
do
  printf "$remaining second(s) remaining\r"
  sleep 1
done
printf "\r\033[K\033[34mTimer Finished\033[0m\n"


make newline afterloop:
read -p"Enter timer length (seconds): " num
printf "Timer starting...now\n"
sleep 1
for ((remaining=$num;remaining>=1;remaining--))
do
  printf "$remaining second(s) remaining\r"
  sleep 1
done
printf "\n\033[34mTimer Finished\033[0m\n"




Boo, hiss re: echo -e and also re: seq

@CharlesDuffy it works fine

The echo use works fine if your shell has a default configuration; it's not robust against all possible sets of runtime flags; the seq use works fine if your OS provides seq at all, and it's a version that supports counting down -- neither of those things is guaranteed. Read Why is printf better than echo? on [unix.se] re the former.

@CharlesDuffy almost all linux distros have seq and yes using it makes a small delay but you cant even notice it because its so small, and about the echo use almost all linux distros use GNU BASH which uses its own echo and not the one in /bin/echo and it has a default configuration of supporting -e and -n, and also shut the fuck up no one cares

Yes, the default configuration supports -e and -n, but the whole point is that not all configuration bash supports are default, so code that only works in the default configuration is unnecessarily fragile. We're building a teaching resource here -- if we can showcase practices that work 100% of the time instead of 98% of the time, that's to the better.

(and just how slow seq is depends -- if one is generating a practically infinite sequence, then needing to store it in RAM and string-split it becomes a serious problem; teach the practice that doesn't have the problems or odd corner cases, and then you don't need to caveat with "oh, but only do this when the set of values fits in available RAM" or other guidelines on how to avoid those problems, or risk creating people who are clueless when one of those pitfalls suddenly applies to them because they're working in a new and different context).

@CharlesDuffy fine then i will edit the stupid solution
